# Formal Verification of Monero code

Tags: monero-research-lab, source-code-documentation

[This answer](https://monero.stackexchange.com/a/1295/193) mentions a plan to eventually [formally verify](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_verification) Monero code. Which approach will be used for that verification process? The cited [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_verification) page mentions [model checking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_checking), deductive verification and [program derivation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_derivation) as possibilities.

Comment: FWIW, I read the comment you linked not as a plan, but a possibility.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If the core Monero daemon gets to a point where it's particularly secure and particularly stable (eg. the code has been formally verified).

Sounds like an idea rather than a particular plan with dates and methods intended for verification. When Monero is particularly secure and particularly stable, then they will probably start discussing methods of verification.